# Organization of repetitive code

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

I have a lot of data organized in `Datasets`. In the end I'm using `ErrorListPlots` to show different variables. Therefore I have to calculate mean values, standard deviations, Sqrt[n]... Afterwards I have to prepare list for plotting containing values, coords, errors.

As shown in this example:

```
values = {32, 39, 27, 30, 32, 14, 28, 21, 32, 24, 32, 41, 26, 27, 37, 
22, 27, 29, 27, 37, 14, 28, 32, 27, 28, 27, 35, 28, 26, 39, 21, 29,
 33, 17, 20, 25, 28, 39, 14, 16, 33, 29, 31, 29, 25, 30, 40, 31, 
32};
values2 = {40, 39, 30, 40, 32, 42, 25, 7, 15, 30, 28, 40, 13, 40, 15, 
33, 31, 17, 19, 22, 29, 38, 30, 29, 29, 20, 17, 16, 13, 21, 19, 20, 
28, 19};

mean = Mean[values]; sd = StandardDeviation[values]; n = Length[values];
sqn = Sqrt[n];
mean2 = Mean[values2]; sd2 = StandardDeviation[values2]; n2 = Length[values2];
sqn2 = Sqrt[n2];

xVal = {10, 15};
yVal = {mean, mean2};
errVal = {sd/sqn, sd2/sqn2};
coordsVal = Riffle[xVal, yVal]; 
tempELPD = Partition[Riffle[coordsVal, errVal, {3, -1, 3}], 3];

tempELP = 
 ErrorListPlot[{tempELPD}, PlotRange -> {{9, 17}, {0, 40}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotStyle -> { Default, Default, Default, Black}]
```

At the moment I did a simple copy and paste (and re-naming of variables) of the example for many variables, but in this way my code gets very long. And since I want to do this now for even a lot more variables and different datasets, I'm thinking about the best possibility to organize the code.

I read some things here and there, but I didn't have a good idea at the moment how to realize this in Mathematica. 
Is it to use a for loop or better using functions for each step?

I'm thankful for every hint.

Comment: Maybe this question was a little to generic, as far as I understood now, functional programming is the "best" solution in Mathematica. And using pure functions is the expert way. Still much to learn...

Answer (score 1):

You can get `yVal` and `errVal` in a single step:

```
{yVal, errVal} = Transpose[Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation[#] / Sqrt[Length @ #]&}@ #]&/@
 {values, values2}];
```

Comment: This is a nice way to shorten the first part. Maybe I can put the second in a function and have than a way better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make my improvements available, I post here an answer to my own question. I'm using kglr's proposal (statFun) and I'm also introducing a faster way to obtain data (ELPD) for the `ErrorListPlots` and a function to show these plots (labelPlotFun).
With these tools I'm able to really safe code lines even for many datasets:

```
statFun[list__] := 
 Transpose[Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation[#]/Sqrt[Length[#]] &}@#] & /@ {list}]

xVal = {10, 15}; 
{yVal, errVal} = statFun[values, values2];

tempELPD = Partition[Riffle[Riffle[xVal, yVal], errVal, {3, -1, 3}], 3];
tempELPD2 = Partition[Riffle[Riffle[xVal + 0.5, yVal], errVal, {3, -1, 3}], 3];

labelPlotFun[label__String, list__List, name__String] := 
 ErrorListPlot[{list}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Axes -> False, ImageSize->Large,
 FrameLabel -> {label}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{name}, Scaled[{0.1, 0.15}],
 PlotRange -> {{9, 18}, {0, 40}}]

tempELP = 
 labelPlotFun["variable x", "variable y", tempELPD, tempELPD2,"data","data shifted"]
```